# Fazer SELECT exibir determinado valor de uma coluna por ultimo, mantendo ordenação por outra coluna

Tags: php, query, select

Estou fazendo o seguinte select em um banco e exibindo o resultado em uma tabela em php:

```
SELECT ID_PRDC, PRDC_ID_PRDT, PRDC_ID_SEM, DATA_PRDC, LINHA.NM_LN, PRODUTO.NM_PRDT,
        SEMI_ACABADO, NUM_OP, LOTE, QTD, PRDC_NUM_SEQ_LN, SITUACAO.DESC_SIT, SITUACAO.ID_SIT, PRDC_ID_LN, PRDC_ID_SIT
        FROM PRODUCAO
        INNER JOIN produto on (PRODUCAO.PRDC_ID_PRDT = PRODUTO.ID_PRDT)
        INNER JOIN linha on (PRODUCAO.PRDC_ID_LN = LINHA.ID_LN)
        INNER JOIN situacao on (PRODUCAO.PRDC_ID_SIT = SITUACAO.ID_SIT)
        WHERE PRDC_ID_SEM = $ult_sem AND DATE_FORMAT( DATA_PRDC, '%Y' ) = $ano_atual 
        ORDER BY PRDC_ID_LN, PRDC_NUM_SEQ_LN
```

Hoje a tabela é montada e ordenada no PHP pela sequencia de *id de linha* o que é o ideal. Cada inserção na tabela **producao** tem um status que são relacionados a tabela **situacao**, o que eu gostaria é que quando uma produção for atualizada para o status *concluido* ou *cancelado* ela passasse a ser exibida no final da lista, mantendo a ordenação do restante por id de linha.

Tentei com 2 SELECTS(um ordenado por linha e outro por status) com UNION ALL mas ele não reconhece um ORDER BY para cada select, tentei ordenar primeiro por id_status e depois por id_linha mas o resultado ordena apenas por id_status e praticamente ignora a ordenação por id_linha.

Exemplo resultado atual:

```
 +------------------------------------------------------------+  
 |                              PRODUCAO                      |
 +------------------+--------------+----------+---------------+
 |    COD PRODUTO   |    PRODUTO   |   LINHA  |     STATUS    |
 +------------------------------------------------------------+
 |      1000001     |     prod1    | 1-linha1 |  2-Produzindo |
 |      2000002     |     prod2    | 1-linha1 |  6-Concluido  |
 |      2000007     |     prod7    | 2-linha2 |  7-Cancelado  |
 |      2000003     |     prod3    | 2-linha2 |  1-Aguardando |
 |      2000005     |     prod5    | 3-linha3 |  6-Concluido  |
 |      3000006     |     prod6    | 4-linha4 |  2-Produzindo |
 |      4000004     |     prod4    | 4-linha4 |  1-Aguardando |
 +------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Exemplo de resultado ideal:

```
 +------------------------------------------------------------+  
 |                          PRODUCAO                          |
 +------------------+--------------+----------+---------------+
 |    COD PRODUTO   |    PRODUTO   |  LINHA   |    STATUS     |
 +------------------------------------------------------------+
 |      1000001     |     prod1    | 1-linha1 |  2-Produzindo |
 |      2000007     |     prod7    | 2-linha2 |  1-Aguardando |
 |      2000005     |     prod5    | 3-linha3 |  2-Produzindo |
 |      2000004     |     prod4    | 4-linha4 |  1-Aguardando |
 |      2000003     |     prod3    | 2-linha2 |  6-Concluido  |
 |      3000006     |     prod6    | 4-linha4 |  6-Concluido  |
 |      4000002     |     prod2    | 1-linha1 |  7-Cancelado  |
 +------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço já pesquisei bastante mas não encontrei nenhum exemplo parecido.

Comment: Dê uma olhada http://stackoverflow.com/a/21211388/6405917
Tenta no seu order by ORDER BY PRDC_ID_LN DESC, PRDC_NUM_SEQ_LN DESC

Comment: Então cara dessa forma ele exibe apenas pela sequencia decrescente os id's de linha, na vdd eu preciso que a coluna PRDC_ID_LN seja ordenada de forma crescente e a outra coluna seria a PRDC_ID_SIT tambem de forma crescente, mas obrigado pela atenção, vou da ruma lida nesse outro topico tbm valeu